# Cannot connect to server port 23 with JSch

Tags: java, telnet, jsch

My JDK is 1.7.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class SSHClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            String host = "192.168.1.233";

            int port = 23;
            String username = "root";
            String password = "htnice";
            // create JSch
            JSch jSch = new JSch();
            // get session
            Session session = jSch.getSession(username, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(prop);
            // start connect
            session.connect();

            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.start_discard(Session.java:1066)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:937)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:309)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at SSHClientTest.main(SSHClientTest.java:26)
```

The same error with jsch-0.1.54 and jsch-0.1.55.

I can connect to the server by TTerm. The port is 23.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JSch is SSH client (port 22).

You cannot use it to connect to Telnet server (port 23).